# File path for email Attachments on server?

Tags: php, path, phpmailer

This is probably a very simple problem but I cant seem to get it right!

I am using `phpMailer` to send an email with attachments I have stored on the server, well thats the plan.

I can get the email to send perfectly as long as the attachment is in the same folder as the sending file eg...

```
$file_to_attach = 'Demo9795.RDP';

$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach);
```

above code works perfect! But i cant send an attachment that is in a different folder.

The email sending file is in the folder: `/webspace/httpdocs/CloudStrong` Partner Management.

And the folder with the files I want to attatch is: `/webspace/httpdocs/uploads`

So basically can anyone tell me how to get the correct path to the files in the uploads folder?

I would be really grateful for any help,

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `$file_to_attach = '/webspace/httpdocs/uploads/Demo9795.RDP';`?

Comment: Ya, tried all different combibations like that, but file just wont attatch if its not in the same folder??

Comment: I don't know. I was never a fan of `phpmailer`.

Comment: Have you tried something to the affect of `$file_to_attach = '../webspace/httpdocs/uploads/Demo9795.RDP';`? Might have to add a few more `../` depending on your structure.

Comment: You might even have to omit the `/webspace/httpdocs` altogether and use `../uploads/Demo9795.RDP`, type of thing or `/uploads/` etc..

Comment: Might be nothing, but try and get rid of that space in `( $file_to_attach)`

Comment: Is it a permissions issue on the directory you are trying to access?

Comment: If your code is trying to access the directory it is usually doing it as the root user, so you need to make sure that root has access to that directory. A quick test is you can check the permissions on the folder that you can access attachments from and make sure they match. Just be careful when modifying folder permissions as you can present security issues. [Documentation](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions)

Comment: Can you try this? `$mailer->AddAttachment('/webspace/httpdocs/uploads/Demo9795.RDP', 'Demo9795.RDP');`

Comment: @user2437588 so, where you at?